# Android - contentResolver.notifyChange() slowing performance

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have a MyContentProvider class that overrides `bulkInsert()`. Within this method, I use a SQLite transaction to insert about 4,000 rows into the database, which takes about 25 seconds on a Samsung Galaxy S4 device.

However, when I **remove** this line from my `bulkInsert()` method...

`getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertedId, null);`

...the total insertion time drops to about 1 or 2 seconds.

So, is there a better way to call `notifyChange()`?

I have tried calling it in another thread, like this...

```
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertedId, null);
                    }
                }).start();
```

...but it's still slow and, for some reason, results in an `OutOfMemoryError`.

For completeness, here is my `bulkInsert()` method...

```
    @Override
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] valuesArray) {

    /*
     *  Open a read / write database to support the transaction.
     */
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String tableName;

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case BRANDS_SEARCH:
            tableName = BRAND_NAMES_TABLE;
            break;
        case PRODUCTS_SEARCH:
            tableName = PRODUCTS_TABLE;
            break;
        case PARENT_COMPANIES_SEARCH:
            tableName = PARENT_COMPANIES_TABLE;
            break;
        case PRODUCTS_DATA_SEARCH:
            tableName = PRODUCTS_DATA_TABLE;
            break;
        default:
            //break;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
    }

    /*
     * Begin the transaction
     */
    db.beginTransaction();

    int numSuccessfulInsertions = 0;

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {

            /*
             *  Insert the values into the table
             */
            long rowId = db.insert(tableName, null, valuesArray[i]);

            if (rowId > -1) {

                /*
                 * Increment numSuccessfulInsertions
                 */
                numSuccessfulInsertions++;

                /*
                 *  Construct the URI of the newly inserted row.
                 */
                Uri insertedId = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, rowId);

                /*
                 *  Notify any observers of the change in the data set.
                 */
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertedId, null);



            }
            else {

                /*
                 * Don't give up (as not all insert attempts need to succeed)
                 */
                //throw new Exception("Could not insert row");
            }

        }

        /*
         * Return number of successful insertions
         */
        return numSuccessfulInsertions;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "bulkInsert exception", e);

        /*
         * Return number of successful insertions
         */
        return numSuccessfulInsertions;

    }
    finally {

        /*
         * Some (or all) insertion attempts succeeded
         */
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        /*
         * Always end the transaction
         */
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notify once for the bulk operation, not once for each record inserted.  Move your call to notifyChange such that it follows the for loop.

Comment: also notify with "dir uri" not "item uri" (not: `content://host/table/1` but whole `content://host/table`)

Comment: To apply the solution, I have added this to the end of my finally block: `if (numSuccessfulInsertions > 0) getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);`